# How to call 3 stored procedure consecutively mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to call 3 stored procedures consecutively using result from previous to call next procedure.

For now, I arrived to call 2 but the third fail.
How can I do please?

This is my code:

```
//First stored procedure CALL
$spots = $mysqli->query("CALL getAllSpots()", MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
while($spot = $spots->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $ville = $row["city"];
    $weather =file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=$ville&mode=json");
    $json = json_decode($weather, true);

    $liste = $json["list"];

    $id = (int) $spot['id'];

    // Free stored results
    clearStoredResults($mysqli);

    // Execute second SP using value from first as a parameter (MYSQLI_USE_RESULT and free result right away)
    $previsions = $mysqli->query("CALL getPrevisionOnSpot($id)", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    $dataRow = $previsions->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $row_cnt = $previsions->num_rows;

    // Free results from second SP
    $previsions->free();
    for ($i = 0; $i<8; $i++){ // Récupère que les données du jour
        $data = $liste[$i];

        // Calcul with $data .........

        //Third call that fail
        if ($row_cnt == 0){
            $result = $mysqli->query("CALL addPrevisionOnSpot($meteo,$temperature,$vitesse,$directionReel,$datetime,$id)",MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
        }
        else {
            $result = $mysqli->query("CALL updatePrevisionOnSpot($meteo,$temperature,$vitesse,$directionReel,$datetime,$id)");
        }
    }

    // And the function to clear stored result
    function clearStoredResults($mysqli_link){
    while($mysqli_link->next_result()){
        if($l_result = $mysqli_link->store_result()){
            $l_result->free();
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch my code, I have bool(false) for third procedure

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: bool(false) for third procedure

Comment: And if your comment `$previsions->free();`, it should work

Comment: if $row_count = 0, execution is ok with always my error for the third stored procedure
But if $row_count != 0, execution stop at id = 2 where i call getPrevisionOnSpot() 
Why ?

Comment: Please edit your post and show me the detail about your procedure called updatePrevisionOnSpot